# How to return multiple results in here.com revgeocode API call?

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Here.com API v6.2 used to have a reverse geocode call that would return multiple records per one call.
Current v1 API has a revgeocode call that returns an array of "items", but it's always limited to 1 item. Is it possible to make it return multiple items?

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the below example:

Example request:

```
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=48.2181679%2C16.389906&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}&limit=10&lang=en-US.
```

Also, you can refer to the below guide:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-reverse-geocode-brief.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html

Comment: Why does the call not return locations around the first location found? The documentation states that the purpose of the call is "to find the nearest address to specific geocoordinates", yet for example in a circle with 100 houses it returns 5 results when you request 100.